# What are the words of House Blackfyre?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

It is of my opinion that House Blackfyre is going to be making a comeback in the person of

> Aegon VI

Now, all the major houses have their words. Starks are "Winter is coming", Martell's words are "Unbowed, unbent, unbroken," and those of House Targaryen are "Fire and Blood." I assume these are just phrases that people of these houses say when going into battle and the such. Even Bittersteel, one of the Great Bastards of Aegon IV, had a semi-house words phrase said before battle: "beneath the gold, the bitter steel," which was adopted by the Golden Company as their battle cry.

Logically, this is a Westerosi custom and I find it likely that every house has its own words. Therefore, what are the words of House Blackfyre, one of the most important houses in recent Westerosi history? Is there any hint as to what they are, or can I just assume for all purposes that Daemon adopted the words of House Targaryen?

Comment: "Blackfyre" is not really a "house". The name came to be after Daemon Blackfyre was considered the rightful heir of Aegon IV "The Unworthy" Targaryen. Hence, he was a Targaryen. The name Blackfyre is the name of the sword Daemon got from his father, the Targaryen family heirloom.

Comment: Except it is referred to as "House Blackfyre" several times. Illyrio `When Maelys the Monstrous died upon the Stepstones, it was the end of the male line of House Blackfyre.`

Comment: You may be right.

Comment: @TLP House Blackfyre was indeed a house. It remains a cadet branch of  House Targaryen (Like Karstarks are cadet branch of House Stark) but a distinct house nevertheless. After his father gave him the sword, Daemon picked the name Blackfyre for himself and reversed colors of Targaryens, thus founding a new dynasty. Even after he was legitimized, He was still called Daemon Blackfyre, not Targaryen. His descendants were also named Blackfyre, not Targaryens.

Comment: Other great bastards did not take Targaryen name either after Aegon's folly. Bloodraven remained Brynden Rivers, Bittersteel remained Aegor Rivers. Bellanora remained Bellanora Otherys. I am not sure about Shiera Seastar but we have never seen any text referring to her as Shiera Targaryen.

Comment: I think they‘re “What even is *fyre* again?”

Comment: Relevant WRT Question of Blackfyres being a unique house: [How did Daemon Waters take the name Blackfyre?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145992/how-did-daemon-waters-take-the-name-blackfyre/146135#146135)

Answer (score 11):

### Unknown.

[A Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Blackfyre) gives us no info on the words of House Blackfyre, and as far as I know this has never been mentioned in either the books or the TV series.

On the level of fanfiction, there's a forum discussion [here](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/74243-house-words/) where people have invented various possibilities for the Blackfyre words, and a [couple](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2waypy/spoilers_all_insight_on_blackfyre_house_words/) of [similar](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/3ewrt4/spoilers_all_words_of_house_blackfyre/) discussions on Reddit. One possibility that comes up time and again is **"Blood and Fire"**, the reversal of the Targaryen words "Fire and Blood", which seems quite fitting considering House Blackfyre's history.

Comment: Read through the possibilities listed. Inverting the Targ words from "Fire and Blood" to "Blood and Fire." A shame Martin has left out such an important but seemingly insignificant detail.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Maybe in the next book, especially if your theory is right ...

Comment: @DJMethaneMan I would say inverted words is a good shout, as the Blackfyre sigil is the Targ sigil with colours inverted.

Answer (score 2):

## We Do Not Know

...And neither does George as he hasn't thought about them yet.

> *Q: What is House Blackfyre's motto?*
>   A: Oh, I don't know. I haven't thought one up yet.
>   <sub>[So Spake Martin, US Signing Tour (Madison, WI)](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/US_Signing_Tour_Madison_WI)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they will be some version of:

"The Only Dragon"

Based on "I am the only dragon that you need." said by Young Griff (supposedly Aegon Targaryen) who may turn out to be a Blackfyre, a Targ, or no one at all.  Aegon and his sister were supposed to have been killed during Robert's Rebellion(as infants), but GRRM has only confirmed the sister is dead leading to speculation by fans.  One sign he is a Blackfyre is the loyalty of the Golden Company (a Blackfyre company by tradition). Varys has stated he himself saved Aegon and that Young Griff is he, but the spider is a known manipulator so his information can't be completely trusted.

Read more about it [here.](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen/Theories)

Comment: Think you mean Varys? Viserys was the other Targaryen.

Comment: Yes, Skooba, thank you.  Edited to reflect comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen "We Bear the Sword" being proposed as potential house words for House BlackFyre. It's an affront to the Targaryen main branch, it's ominous, a good battle cry, and as good a threat as any. I like it. Everything is conjecture at this point until Grum deceides on the words of course. But I like these, more than any I've seen.

Comment: Where have you seen this?

Comment: The Wars and Poltics of Ice and Fire blog has been making a habit of inventing House Words for the Houses that lack them as of yet. A lot of them are pretty meh I really don't feel their suggestion for House Florent for example ("Listen carefully").